# Numerical software to solve partial differential equations in spherical coordinates?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, math-software, spherical-geometry

Which numerical libraries / math software can allow me to solve partial differential equations in spherical coordinates? (my system consists of N degrees of freedom, each degree lives in $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ and the whole system is $(\mathbb{C}^{2})^{N}$).

Answer (score 1):

You can look into MudPack to see if this helps for your problem here: [MUDPACK](http://nldr.library.ucar.edu/collections/technotes/asset-000-000-000-167.pdf)

Hope this helps a bit.

Good Luck.